# Different package for different user agent

Tags: admin, theme, package

I have 2 custom themes in magento. One is in default package and second is in SEPARATE package.Just like Below

- default

  - iphone
  - default
- magma

  - default

Now using design exception i want to use the default of magma.Can anyone help me how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

```
System -> Configuration -> Design
```

If you click on the "Add Exception" you could define a new regular-expression followed by the package-name. As an example, a valid expression could be:

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini
```

There is already a conversion about design-regex`s [here.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5650/configuring-design-exception-strings-for-mobile-devices)

If you want more infos just take a look at the method where the magic happens ;-) *Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::getPackageByUserAgent*

```
 /**
 * Return package name based on design exception rules
 *
 * @param array $rules - design exception rules
 * @param string $regexpsConfigPath
 * @return bool|string
 */
public static function getPackageByUserAgent(array $rules, $regexpsConfigPath = 'path_mock')
{
    foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        if (!empty(self::$_regexMatchCache[$rule['regexp']][$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']])) {
            self::$_customThemeTypeCache[$regexpsConfigPath] = $rule['value'];
            return $rule['value'];
        }

        $regexp = '/' . trim($rule['regexp'], '/') . '/';

        if (@preg_match($regexp, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
            self::$_regexMatchCache[$rule['regexp']][$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']] = true;
            self::$_customThemeTypeCache[$regexpsConfigPath] = $rule['value'];
            return $rule['value'];
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```