# how to set store views depending device (mobile / desktop) using Mage::run?

Tags: store-view

I have created an additional store-view which I want to display if user is on a mobile device.

Saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062166/best-way-to-detect-mobile-users-in-magento), but I don't want to create an additional store

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Design "Exception" Strings for "Mobile" Devices](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5650/configuring-design-exception-strings-for-mobile-devices)

Comment: Anna, unfortunately it wont work on this specific case, as there's some customization on homepage (menu system, theme and slider), which was way easier to implement on separate store view / homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow bellow steps:**

**Step : 1** Open `index.php` file at magento root folder and add bellow code in before `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`

```
$mobile_agents = "/(nokia|iphone|android|motorola|^mot\-|softbank|foma|docomo|kddi|up\.browser|up\.link|"  
                 . "htc|dopod|blazer|netfront|helio|hosin|huawei|novarra|CoolPad|webos|techfaith|palmsource|"  
                 . "blackberry|blackberry10|bb10|playbook|alcatel|amoi|ktouch|nexian|samsung|^sam\-|s[cg]h|^lge|ericsson|philips|sagem|wellcom|bunjalloo|maui|"  
                 . "symbian|smartphone|mmp|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|iemobile|^spice|^bird|^zte\-|longcos|pantech|gionee|^sie\-|portalmmm|"  
                 . "jig\s browser|hiptop|^ucweb|^benq|haier|^lct|opera\s*mobi|opera\*mini|320x320|240x320|176x220"  
                 . ")/i";  
if (preg_match($mobile_agents, strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
     $mageRunCode = 'mobile';  // your store view code
}
```

Make sure add you store view code. We have added my store view code  `$mageRunCode = 'mobile';`

**Step : 2** After clear cache and show both way in desktop & mobile device.

If any queries let me know :)

Comment: No need to edit index.php, see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5650/configuring-design-exception-strings-for-mobile-devices/5752

Comment: he is need to using Mage::run

Comment: I see, added my own answer then.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach than editing the `index.php` (which is not update-safe) is to set this value via `.htaccess`.

You can use `SetEnvIf` or `SetEnvIfNoCase` (without respect to case) for this:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent .*iphone.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_storeview
SetEnvIf User-Agent .*android.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_storeview
```

or

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*iphone.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_storeview
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*android.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=mobile_storeview
```

Comment: Thank you Anna, will keep in mind and make recommendation to store owner.

Comment: its not working for me