# How to use Different themes for Mobile App & site

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, mobile, app

I am new to Magento and I am planning to create a mobile app for my store. Since I cannot build or afford a mobile app for myself, I am planning to build a mobile app that simply redirects to my website but with different theme that I would like to use to make more easy for app users.

If anyone know how this can be done please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can do this by Magento admin. Go to `System > Configuration > General > Design -> Package and Theme sections`.

Click `Matched Expression` and this:

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini
```

This settings will be use for detecting Mobile devices.

You can create New Package and Theme for mobile devices as shown below:

[image]

From above, 
create new Package at : `\app\design\frontend\mobile_package\`

and Theme at : `\app\design\frontend\mobile_package\mobile\`

For more visit [here](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-design-exceptions-explained/) OR SO answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5650/configuring-design-exception-strings-for-mobile-devices)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How will I edit my mobile theme as active theme will be the desktop/laptop theme?

Comment: check updated answer