# How to give user agent rule for iPad and Tablet in Magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, mobile, rules

I have two themes, one for mobile and other for desktop. I have created 2 user agent rules for Mobile and iPad. All mobiles are showing mobile theme. But iPad and Tablets are also showing mobile theme. I need iPad and Tablets to show desktop theme. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `mobile` user agent includes the iPad. To workaround this you'll need to specify the mobiles individually.

> Note that the Safari on iPad user agent string contains the word "Mobile", but does not contain the word "iPhone". If you are currently serving mobile content to any browser that self-identifies as "Mobile", you should modify your user agent string checks to look for iPad and avoid sending it the wrong version of your site.

For example:

**Mobile theme**

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|BB10|Pre|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|mobi|Safari Mobile|Windows Mobile|Android|Opera Mini|mobile
```

**Desktop theme**

```
iPad|Silk|Kindle|Xoom|SCH-I800|GT-P5210|Android Tablet|Tablet|SM-T520|hudl|HT7S3|ME173X|JSS15Q|Nexus 7|Nexus 8|Nexus 9|Nexus 10
```

If that doesn't work try also removing `mobi`. That list is a few years old now so you may need to add some more if you find new devices aren't working as you'd expect.

Some info taken from [this M1 answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5650/configuring-design-exception-strings-for-mobile-devices)

Comment: Hello @Ben Crook, I want solution for Magento 2..

Comment: the design exceptions haven't changed much, my answer applies to both.

Comment: Doesn't work for magento 2.3.5:(