# Layered filter won't display on mobile

Tags: frontend, uicomponent, filter, mobile

I am very new to `Magento`, so please bear with me if I'm not doing this correctly.

What I need to do is display a filter for `sizing` on a `category page` on the `mobile versions` of my company's application. I am able to display this on the desktop site by doing two things:

- **Catalog > properties > Use in layered navi > filterable (with
  results)**
- **Catalog > manage categories > display settings > is anchor > yes**

I'm not sure if by enabling these `two settings` in the `admin panel` would `automatically display` a filter on the `mobile version` as well because I joined this company well after a ton of `customization` had been done.

I have inspected the page to make sure that no `"filter"(s)` of any sort were commented out and found nothing.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: have you checked the css media query, it might hide the layered navigation. When you open the site with browser and resize the browser to mobile size, does the layered navigation gone? if it's not gone then you might need to check your magento user agent https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/182172/51758

Comment: pass your site url to check

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. I will check to see what's going on first thing tomorrow at work to see if there are any media queries that are giving me problems and report back.

Comment: after admin settings change you need to run "bin/magento indexer:reindex && bin/magento cache:flush" to be sure is not a caching or indexing issue